# Wrap all images in output using php

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to wrap all `img` tags in my output text:

```
$output = '<p>some text <img src=""> some text  <img src=""></p>
           <p>some text <img src=""> some text  <img src=""></p>';
```

I need it to be:

```
$output = '<p>some text <figure><img src=""><figcaption>blah blah</figcaption></figure> some text  <figure><img src=""><figcaption>blah blah</figcaption></figure></p><p>some text <figure><img src=""><figcaption>blah blah</figcaption></figure> some text  <figure><img src=""><figcaption>blah blah</figcaption></figure></p>';
```

Can I do that with regexp?

Comment: You might not want to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Comment: You cannot parse HTML with regex. HE COMES!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_replace()`. In the replacement, `$0` gets replaced with whatever the regular expression matched.

```
$output = preg_replace('/<img[^>]*>/', '<figure>$0<figcaption>blah blah</figcaption></figure>', $output);
```